# Summing cells that have formula and string concatenated together

Tags: excel

I have a column with formula as follows:

```
=(2+3*6+8) & "KB"
```

Basically, each cell is a formula and string concatenated (using `&`).  I want to add all these cells up. I tried the following things:

a) `=SUM(B2:B21)` gives me a sum of `0`.

b) Using `=B2+B3...` gives me a `#VALUE` error.

c) I tried something like this also - didn't work, gives a sum of `0`: `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("KB",$C$2:$C$14)),VALUE(LEFT($C$2:$C$14,FIND("KB",$C$2:$C$14)-1)),0))`

Comment: if it is always "KB" then something like `{=SUM(LEFT(B2:B21,LEN(B2:B21)-2)*1)}` or `{=SUM(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B21,"KB","")*1)}` will do the trick... input without the `{}` and confirm formula with ctrl+shift+enter)

Comment: Formulas are difficult to maintain. I always just create a VBA function because VBA is more readable and then the user gets a readable formula function with proper parameter names. Check out my answers.

Comment: **If it is always KB**, why use `=(2+3*6+8) & "KB"`? You can use `=(2+3*6+8)` and use the custom formatting `#,##0" KB";-#,##0" KB"`. This will enable you to do all calculations as any other number while avoiding text formula. If it is data you have received you can just use Ctrl + h and replace `& "KB"` and then apply the custom formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own SUM function in VBA. Try this:

`=StripTextAndSum(A2:A4)` - returns 60
`=StripTextAndAverage(A2:A4)` - returns 20

This method keeps the left most *decimal* number and tosses away the rest.

[image]
[image]

**NOTE:** You can tweak this to fit your needs. One way would be to retain the text so you can return it in the sum....like 150MB (i am assuming KB means kilobyte). Let me know if you like that idea and I'll make it.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @DirkReichel, this has been made a little more efficient using `IsNumeric` instead, but I have retained all the other functions too. `IsLetter` is a useful function too.

```
Public Function StripTextAndSum(myRange As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim n As Double
    n = 0
    For Each r In myRange.Cells
        n = n + ParseNumberFromString(r.Text)
    Next r

    StripTextAndSum = n

End Function

Public Function StripTextAndAverage(myRange As Range)
    Dim n As Double
    n = StripTextAndSum(myRange)
    StripTextAndAverage = n / (myRange.Cells.Count * 1#)
End Function

Public Function ParseNumberFromString(s As String) As Double

    ParseNumberFromString = Left(s, GetLastNumberIndex(s))

End Function


Public Function GetFirstLetterIndex(s As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(s) Step 1
        If IsLetter(Mid(s, i, 1)) = True Then
            GetFirstLetterIndex = i
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next i
End Function

Public Function GetLastNumberIndex(s As String) As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
            If IsNumeric(Left(s, i)) = True Then
                GetLastNumberIndex = i
                Exit Function
            End If

        Next i
    End Function

Function IsLetter(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If LCase(Mid(s, i, 1)) <> UCase(Mid(s, i, 1)) = True Then
            IsLetter = True
        Else
            IsLetter = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I suggest to simplify the part to get the number like: `Function MyNumber(s As String) As Double: Dim i: For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1:If IsNumeric(Left(s, i)) Then:MyNumber = Left(s, i): Exit Function: End If: Next: End Function` ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel You're probably right...I wanted to include the IsLetter function though since it is not part of VBA like IsNumeric. I'll update it... thanks

Comment: For the `IsLetter`-part, you just need to check `LCase(Mid(s, i, 1)) <> UCase(Mid(s, i, 1))`... if true, then it is a letter ;)

Comment: Nice! I'm going to use that!

Comment: I changed the IsLetter function instead. This allows that to perform better and still handle a collection of characters. I also think it makes `GetFirstLetterIndex` more readable with `IsLetter` in there.

Comment: Just have in mind that it will fail for... umm... German... there is no uppercase `ß` :P (you are running `IsLetter` just for single letters. In theory, there is no need for the loop in there)

Comment: try it...it will return true for `aaaaaaa` and `abcDeFg`, but false for `aaaa1aaa`

Comment: Should I add a note about the language? Did you see I added an Average function :) I could convert it to work more like Subtotal in that you choose the aggregation in a param...

Comment: I was just looking at the only point you are calling `IsLetter` and there it only submits a single character each loop ;) There is no real need for a note about the language... we do know that the `ß` is special and needs to be checked directly...

Comment: Your `If` condition in `IsLetter` is a little too much. What you do now is checking `LCase<>UCase`, this will give you `True/False` and then you check `True/False = True` and it will give you `True/False`. Same thing in `Get...` functions when using `IsLetter/IsNumeric`. It is working, but comparison to `True` is not necessary.

Comment: @EganWolf a lot could be better, but this is a good example that executes quickly and gives the correct results. These functions are not specific to this answer. I might compromise performance for a reusable function. What if I wanted to retain the text? I have a function that gives me the last index of the number so I just go right from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd normally just move the `KB` to the following column and left-justify it.

That way, it still *looks* identical but the first column only has real numbers that you can manipulate mathematically to your heart's content.

Or, assuming they're all in kilobytes (which seems to be a requirement if you just want to add the numeric bits), don't put `KB` in the data area at all.

Instead change the heading from, for example, `Used memory` to `Used memory (KB)`.

Do you really *want* to populate your beautiful spreadsheets with butt-ugly monstrosities like the following? :-)

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("KB",$C$2:$C$14)),VALUE(LEFT($C$2:$C$1‌​4,FIND("KB",$C$2:$C$‌​14)-1)),0))
```

Comment: VBA gives the option to keep the crappy formatting without the butt-ugly monstrosities although one could argue that VB is butt-ugly lol.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to keep your column as-is, you could always use an array formula to get the sum:

```
=sum(value(left(b2:b21,len(b2:b21)-2)))
```

You will need to enter this as an array formula (press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to submit it)

Basically this is taking the leftmost chunk of a cell (all but the last two characters, which we know are 'KB'), using `value()` to convert it into a numeric, and `sum()` to add it up. Entering it as an array formula just lets us do this to each cell in the list b2:b21 in one swoop.

As @paxdiablo mentioned, though, it might be best to restructure so that you don't have to deal with your values as text in the first place. My approach would be to enter the values and add the "KB" via formatting. You can use a custom formatting with something like `0.00 "KB"` so the cell only holds, say, the value 17, but it displays as "17.00 KB".